# launch file parameters that have curly braces

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, yaml, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Melodic.
How can I set a parameter in a launch file that resembles a yaml syntax like this:

```
scan: {sensor_frame: base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

I know that generally, when there are parameters like:

```
SOMETHING:
  key: value
  foo: bar
```

it's sufficient to do `<param name="SOMETHING/key" value="value" />`, but I don't think it's the same for the curly braces, or is it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338648/launch-file-parameters-that-have-curly-braces/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use something like this,

```
<node pkg="my_pkg" name="my_node" type="my_node">
  <rosparam>
    key: value
    foo: bar
  </rosparam>
</node>
```

EDIT:

You can also make a yaml file and load it in your launch file like
`<rosparam file="$(find my_pkg)/config/my_params.yaml" />`

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-27**:
does this work with curly braces too? being

```
  <rosparam>
    key: {a: $(arg foo)/value, b: $(arg foo)/value}
    foo: bar
  </rosparam>
```

**EDIT**: no, I'm sorry but it doesn't. The error says it clearly: `RLException: error loading <rosparam> tag: Error within YAML block: mapping values are not allowed here`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-27**:
Everything in a `rosparam` tag is pure yaml. So dictionaries (what you call "curly braces") are fully supported. See the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam).

---

Edit: o, you want to *replace* parts based on `roslaunch` `arg`s? You'll have to enable substitution for that (ie: set `subst_value` to `True`).

Again: refer to [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam).

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-27**:
Never tried it but probably `key/a:` should work too. And if you want to use a dictionary, I have used it and it works. `key: {'a': $(arg foo)/value, 'b': $arg(foo)/value}` should work I guess.